# Unable to extract symbols from string

Tags: php, string, escaping, symbols

I am trying to use some specific symbols in a string. I need to loop through each character of the string and identify the symbols.
However, certain symbols are getting converted to THREE CHARACTERS.
Need help on how to retain the symbol.

```
echo $instring = ("& ∨ = ⊢");
echo "\nLength of string: ".strlen($instring); 
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($instring) ; $i++){
    $temp_str = substr($instring, $i,1);
    echo "\nChar: $i: $temp_str";
    $instring_arr[$i] = $temp_str;
}
```

---

### HERE IS THE WORKING CODE. Thanks to h2oooooo:

```
echo $instring = ("& ∨ = ⊢");
echo "\nLength of string: ".mb_strlen($instring, "UTF-8"); 
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($instring, "UTF-8") ; $i++){
    $temp_str = mb_substr($instring, $i,1,"UTF-8");
    echo "\nChar: $i: $temp_str";
    $instring_arr[$i] = $temp_str;
}
```

Comment: That's because `substr` and `strlen` works on an ascii basis (every character is considered 1 byte - `0-255` or `00000000-11111111` in binary), and these characters are unicode (each character can be up to [*6* bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)). Use the [multibyte functions](http://dk1.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) [`mb_substr`](http://www.php.net/mb_substr) and [`mb_strlen`](http://www.php.net/mb_strlen) instead.

Comment: Hi h2ooooooo, You made my day! I don't know how to "accept" / vote for your answer. I will post the working code. THanx a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can juste split the string, put all the parts on Table (or List or ever else) and check all the Table till you find your specific symbols.

Hope I help you.

Comment: Thanks but I don't thunk it'll work. PHP is treatin. Certain symbols, like the one that looks like v, as three characters. The length of the string is also being reported as a higher value.